# View Model not updating on save or on textInput

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

This is most likely a simple fix but I'm bashing my head against the wall here. So I have a JSON response from the server which I'm happing to my viewmodel with `ko.mapping`. The data is bound to an input text field. However the view model isn't updating.

What I'm expecting is if the input text field is updated, the view model is updated, and the `<p>` is updated above it (which is bound to the same field).

Any ideas on why my viewmodel isn't updating?

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "notes": [
    {
      "key": "Field1",
      "value": "Progress"
    },
    {
      "key": "Field2",
      "value": "Plan"
    }
  ]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: notes -->
    <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-12">
            <p data-bind="text: value()"></p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: value()" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-12">
            <!-- ko ifnot:editingItem-->
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" data-bind="click: $parent.editRow">Edit</a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:editingItem-->
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" data-bind="click: $parent.stopEdit">Cancel</a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

**JS**

```
 var mapping = {
    'notes': {
        create: function (item) {
            // console.log(item);
            return new Note(item.data.key, item.data.value, false);
        }
    }
 }

 function Note(key, value, editing) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = ko.observable(value);
    this.editingItem = ko.observable(editing);
 }

 function NotesModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.notes = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.Save = function () {
        console.log(ko.toJSON(self));
    };
    self.editRow = function (item) {
        //Stop editing other rows
        $.each(self.notes, function (i, v) {
            v.editingItem(false);
        });
        item.editingItem(true);
    }
    self.stopEdit = function (item) {
        item.editingItem(false);
    }
 };
 var notesModel = new NotesModel();
 ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, notesModel);
 ko.applyBindings(notesModel, $('#CIR_NotesFields')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the bind from "textInput" to just value and remove the explicit observable reference from you "

" binding just like the markup below.

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: notes -->
    <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-12">
            <p data-bind="text: value"></p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: value" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-12">
            <!-- ko ifnot:editingItem-->
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" data-bind="click: $parent.editRow">Edit</a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:editingItem-->
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" data-bind="click: $parent.stopEdit">Cancel</a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c9t1oagv/

Comment: thank you! What was the issue with the bindings? And how did the explicit observable reference affect it? Just for future reference?

Comment: Knockout uses a set of binding keywords, "value" and "text" in your mark up for example. and it only recognizes those ... in your code you used "textInput" and that is not a defined binding keyword. refer to the section "bindings" for existing bindings in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html. and by "explicit observable reference" I mean adding the brackets at the end of the observable variables (effectively making them function calls) and binding to a value in stead of the observable it self.